# Can't move_uploaded_file using PHP, CHMOD 777

Tags: php, file, upload, chmod

I'm having a little problem with PHP's move_uploaded_file.
The CHMOD for the PHP file and directory is 777.
The code is as follows:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$target_path = "upl/" . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']; 
if(in_array(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowedExts) && $_FILES['file']['size'] <= 10485760){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "Skopiuj to i wklej do wpisu:<br>";
        echo "<input type='text' value='[img]http://***********/upl/" . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "[/img]'>";
    }else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
}
```

The code gives the error, despite the chmod.

Comment: That code is highly dangerous. You're directly using the user-provided `['name']` as the final destination of the file. A malicious user can embed pathing information and you'll allow them to scribble their file ANYWHERE on your server. At least you're only allowing image-type filenames, but it's still dangerous. And you're simply assuming the upload was successful. Did you bother checking `['error']` before trying your move call? move will fail if there's no valid upload to actually BE moved.

Comment: Just checked for errors, none returned. I removed all the safety measures trying to find out why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Many possibilities. Are you positive the file upload is received correctly? Check [$_FILES['file']['error']](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Is the uploaded file larger than [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) or [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)?

Does the server use [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)? If so, are you writing the file to a directory which is enabled?

For what its worth -- setting file mode 777 on the containing directory is pretty risky. You are enabling write access for all users on the server. Have you considered a more restrictive setting, perhaps 774? This would enable to web group to write files in the directory, but regular users could only read files.

In your example code you are trusting the file name as uploaded by the client. Have you considered the security implications?

Comment: open_basedir | no value | no value

Comment: The filesize is LESS than the maximum filesize.

Comment: Did you check post_max_size? Is the HTML FORM tag enctype attribute set to "multipart/form-data"?